# seg fault when running arm-elf-gcc compiled code

Tags: macos, embedded, arm, elf

Using MacPorts i have just installed arm-elf-gcc on to my MacBook Pro. This worked flawlessly and all seems to run fine.

However, after compiling a simple hello world test program in C and C++ and trying to run either on the target board (an ARM9 based board running Debian Linux) they immediately seg fault.

I'm a bit stuck as how to go about debugging this, as the target board has limited tools available and no gdb. I have successfully built and run other code using a Linux hosted cross compiler so it should work.

Any ideas?

Following the suggestion I have built and run gdbserver, I get the following in gdb on the host:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()

I thought it may be a problem with the standard c libs so I removed any calls and have just an empty main that return 0, it is compiled with *-Wall -g hello-arm.cpp -static*. As a test I compiled the same source with a Linux hosted cross compiler and it runs and exits fine. The only difference I can see is the that Linux compiled version is over twice the size and the difference in output from the *file* command:

arm-elf-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, statically linked, not stripped

arm-*-linux: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.4.18, not stripped

Answer (score 2):

The usual method of debugging in this situation is to run gdbserver on the target board, and connect to it (via ethernet) with gdb running on a host computer.

Alternately, you could try comparing the assembly in a Mac-compiled "Hello World" program and a (working) Linux-compiled one to see what's different.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around for a couple of days I am starting to understand a bit more about embedded compilers. I wasn't really sure of the difference between arm-elf-gcc installed via MacPorts and the arm-unknown-linux toolchain I had installed on my Linux box. I just came across a pdf titled "[An introduction to the GNU compiler](http://www.zap.org.au/elec2041-cdrom/unsw/common/compiler-intro.pdf)" which contains the following paragraph:

> Important: Using the GNU Compiler to
>   create your executable is not quite
>   the same as using the GNU Linker,
>   arm-elf-ld, yourself.  The reason is
>   that the GNU Compiler automatically
>   links a number of standard system
>   libraries into your executable.  These
>   libraries allow your program to
>   interact with an operating system, to
>   use the standard C library functions,
>   to use certain language features and
>   operations (such as division), and so
>   on.  If you wish to see exactly which
>   libraries are being linked into the
>   executable, you should pass the
>   verbose flag
>   -v to the compiler.
>
> This has important implications for
>   embedded systems!  Such systems do not
>   usually have an operating system. 
>   This means that linking in the system
>   libraries is almost always
>   meaningless: if there is no operating
>   system, for example, then calling the
>   standard printf function does not make
>   much sense.

So when I get back to my dev machine later I will determine the libraries linked in with the Linux build and add them to the arm-elf-gcc build.

I'll update this when I have more information but I just want to document my findings in case any one else has these problems.

Comment: I'm going through the same issue now. Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: I didn't really get to the bottom of this and I think that was more to do with my misunderstanding of the issue. However I did get a working ARM cross compiler working by installing Crosspack ARM from http://www.obdev.at/products/crosspack/index.html.